# binary search fuction always returns -1 value instead of index

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

My Binarysearch function returns -1 always instead of index even if the data is present in the array.Can anyone please help me in figuring out the problem

```
int main(){

    int ar[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int i,w;
    cout<<"enter the element to search"<<endl;
    cin>>w;
    int y  = binarysearch(ar,w,0,9);
    cout<<y<<" index"<<endl;
    return 0;
    }

    int binarysearch(int ar[],int x,int p,int r)
    {

        int q;
        if(p==r)
        {
            if(ar[r]==x)
                {
                    return r;
                }
            else
               {
                    return -1;
               }
        }
        else{
            q = ((r+p)/2);
              if(x<ar[q])
                 {
                     return(binarysearch(ar,x,p,q));
                 }
                  else
                    return(binarysearch(ar,x,q+1,r));
    }


    }
```

Comment: I anyone downvotes then please provide me suggestion how I ask this question in an better way

Comment: If `x == ar[q]`, you call `binarysearch` recursively in a way that excludes `q` from further consideration. In effect, you make sure that the element will *not* be found.

Comment: Sir how to make suitable corrections

Comment: Generally by opening the source file in your favorite text editor, and using your keyboard to make changes. I'm not going to do your homework for you, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: See: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Sorry for asking the question in vague way @Igor Tandetnik due to which you misunderstood the question I got the reason. I took the analogy of an stick to understand my mistake when I break it into two parts I was not including the last end of 1st part  initially so there was problem but now I understood after this analogy.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct.

Issue is in the condition i.e. `if(x<ar[q])`.

Consider array:

```
int arr[11] = 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

its indices are:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

consider user passed `w=50`, middle index `q` is computed to 5

The condition `if(x<ar[q])` will be false because 50 is not less than 50. so its else part i.e. `return(binarysearch(ar,x,q+1,r));` will be run i.e. `return(binarysearch(ar,50,6,10));` Here the code takes the wrong turn. We start looking in the wrong subarray.

The item `50` we are looking for is in the first subarray i.e. `0 10 20 30 40 50`, not in the second subarray i.e. `60 70 80 90 100`.

One way to fix your code is to make the condition `if(x<ar[q])` as `if(x<=ar[q])`. Or you can add another if condition that just checks for equality and adjust q as required in other ifs.